# How to offer my program as choice when user click link to google maps?

Tags: android, maps

I have program with maps. When user click url link containing 'mymaps.com' - my program shows in chooser dialog as alternative of web browser.
I want to do same when user click link to google maps /web or application generated/.
I have found different url formats:

- http://m.google.com/u/m/zIOcsV
- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45.089036,+-106.347656&num=1&t=h&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&z=4&iwloc=A

I suppouse there are other formats too.
Does anybody know how to intercept all formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an intent filter! See here for more info : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

In your android manifest, add the following in your  tag for the activity you want to open :

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.maps" android:pathPrefix="/maps" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then in your Activity
create a method called : handleIntent like so

```
private void handleIntent(Intent newIntent) {
      Uri myuri = newIntent.getData();
      (then use myuri to get your parameters such as q, num, etc)
      (then show your map or whatever else you like with that data)

}
```

in your onCreate you will need to call handleIntent like so

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    (init stuff would go here)
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

(optional) You may need to override the onNewIntent like so  (just in case your AndroidManifest activity configchanges property is tweaked)

```
@Override 
protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    setIntent(newIntent);
    handleIntent(newIntent);
}
```

Comment: Your post is OK. One problem cannot be solved: shortened link. /if I don't know koordinates - lins is useles. Unfortunately in gogle maps for android links are shortened :(

Comment: Shortened links usually redirect to the un-shortened version...but,  you can always add another `<data.../>` scheme to resolve these too.

Comment: Petey - I'm not using google maps. We have own maps and map engine. My program use external links to get coords and open on my map, not google map.